# Call c# method from javascript for a redirect

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a c# method for a redirect

```
[UIAuthentication()]
[UIMethod("cancelredirect", "mth"), UIMethodGroup("employeradmin")]
public void CancelRedirect(RequestContext Context)
{
  Context.Redirect(string.Format("View.mth?EmployerID={0}", _employerID));
}
```

From this I have made a javascript function which is called if the cancel button on a form is pressed.

```
function getCancel() {
    var confirmCancel = confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel?');
    if(confirmCancel)
    {
      //redirect here
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
    };

<input type="submit" id="Cancel" value="Cancel" name="Cancel" class="input_button" onclick="return getCancel();"/>
```

I was just wondering how would you call the c# method from the javascript to redirect to the page view.mth? I am not 100% sure how to do this as I have never done one one these before. Thanks for any help which you can give

Comment: why not redirect from client side ?

Comment: Would Javascript be able to redirect that style link?

Comment: @willa: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/503093/328193

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question should be: "How to call action method from java-script?"

Assuming your controller class name: EmployeeController

```
if(confirmCancel)
{
  document.location = = '/Employee/CancelRedirect';
}
```

Please go through following link for more info: [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

when you call server method by ajax, you can't do  Redirect ,because the response handler is not the page.

If the purpose you call `CancelRedirect` just only to get one variable , the `EmployerID` from server side.

you can get `EmployerID` by Ajax and when the front side get the `EmployerID` , just redirect by :

```
window.location = "/View.mth?EmployerID=xxxx";
```

Ps: maybe you should make the ajax `async` property to `false`

Answer (score 0):

try with ajax :

```
if(confirmCancel)
{
var url = '/Employee/CancelRedirect';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data :{ valeur : if you want to send a value }
            })
}
```